# Sympy: generate figure with multiple subplots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

I'm using sympy and matplotlib, and wish to generate a figure with multiple plots, similarly to how it's done using pylab.subplot when using numpy. This should be trivial, or so I thought...

To my surprise I didn't find a simple way to do it. Either (a) evaluate a SymPy expression at multiple points and get a numpy array which I can use with matplotlib or (b) use a mechanism similar to pylab.subplot in sympy.plotting.

Sample code:

```
import sympy.plotting.plot as symplot
import sympy as sym
x = sym.Symbol('x')
# This opens two different figures...
symplot(x*x, (x, -10, 10))
symplot(x, (x, -10, 10))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This question is a bit too abstract I think.  Editing with some concrete examples might help ...

Comment: Do you want subplots or two lines superimposed on the same plot? I have answered assuming the first one. For the second one, just group your expressions.

Comment: I want matplotlib style, as you understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you can use `lambdify()` to convert an expression to a function:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *

x, y = symbols("x, y")
eq = sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

xa = np.random.rand(10)
ya = np.random.rand(10)
f = lambdify((x, y),eq,'numpy')

print f(xa, ya)
print np.sqrt(xa**2 + ya**2)
```

Comment: `lambdify` fails on any non-trivial input. For fancy stuff you can loop with `expression.evalf(subs=arg)` over the array of values, but this is done in python and in higher-than-machine precision, so it is slow.

Comment: This is a little silly, because I don't need to lambda; just the function evaluated at certain plots... Being better than nothing, I'll try it.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the version of SymPy that you are using.

In the latest version (0.7.2) you already have a plotting module that is guaranteed to be able to plot *anything* and that can use as a backend matplotlib.

In older versions you have the option to use `lambdify` which is a hackish, mostly broken helper function that returns a fast numerical function to be used with numpy. However it breaks for non-trivial expressions.

Below I explain how to use the plotting module in 0.7.2:

1. Just call `plot` like in `p = plot(expression, (var, start, stop))`. If you have `matplotlib` it will use it directly.
2. If you want something fancy, extract the `matplotlib` figure: `f = p._backend.fig`.
3. Stop caring about SymPy, the rest of your work is in `matplotlib`. You can do whatever you want.

The idea behind SymPy's plotting module is to be able to evaluate any possible expression, not to reimplement a plotting library like matplotlib. So just use `sympy.plotting.plot` for evaluation and do the fancy subplot transformations in matplotlib.

Using the sympy plotting module has other advantages over hackish solutions: detection of discontinuities and adaptive sampling, coloring depending on a function, evaluation of pathologically complicated symbolic expressions (although slow).

And obviously, check the docs. While they are not great, many questions are answered there: http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/plotting.html Check also the notebooks in the example folder of sympy.

EDIT to address some additional questions:

1. There is no notion of subplots in the SymPy's plotting module, and hopefully there will never be one. As I mentioned above, SymPy is not trying to reimplement modules like `matplotlib`, rather it is trying to give the tools necessary for good easy use within another module (interfaces between modules are better than big project with many small submodules).
2. In order to create one figure with two subplots in matplotlib from two different sympy plots do (this is an ugly hack, as matplotlib does not support merges of figures):

   ```
   sympy_p1 = sympy.plot(foo)
   sympy_p2 = sympy.plot(bar)
   matplotlib_fig = plt.figure()
   sp1 = matplotlib_fig.add_subplot(121)
   sp2 = matplotlib_fig.add_subplot(122)
   sp1.add_collection(sympy_p1._backend.ax.get_children()[appropriate_index])
   sp2.add_collection(sympy_p2._backend.ax.get_children()[appropriate_index])
   matplotlib_fig.show()
   ```
3. In order to update sympy plot (not creation of a subplot, just adding a new expression) use `sympy_p1.append(sympy_p2)`. This will result in `sympy_p1` containing the plots of both `foo` and `bar` (**NOT** two subplots, rather one plot with both expressions).
4. You might want to use `sympy.plot(..., show=False)` in some cases.

Comment: The thing I miss and also the docs don't say is how to cause sympy to reuse a figure rather than opening a new one. In your suggestion, how do I generate two plots using sympy in two different subplots of matplotlib? Thanks!

Comment: @UriCohen, I think I have answered your questions in the edit that I made above. I have not tested the code but it should work - if there is a problem just warn me and I will fix it.

Comment: I think the latest version of sympy don't have _backend in the Plot object, just backend which is a DefaultBackend instance without an ax member...

Comment: The `_backend` attribute is created on `show` or `save`. It is there and it is different from `backend`.

Comment: I have fixes the code. It seems `matplotlib` does not permit merges of figures. I doubt that subplots will be implemented on the side of `sympy` as it would just duplicate a lot of the matplotlib functionality. In a perfect world figure merges functionality will be added to matplotlib.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the second part could be using the PlotGrid class:

```
>>> p1 = plot(x*x, (x, -10, 10), show=False)
>>> p2 = plot(x, (x, -10, 10), show=False)   
>>> PlotGrid(2, 1 , p1, p2)     # grid size or subplot size: 2x1
PlotGrid object containing:
Plot[0]:Plot object containing:
[0]: cartesian line: x*x for x over (x, -10, 10)
Plot[1]:Plot object containing:
[0]: cartesian line: x for x over (x, -10, 10)
```

This feature is not a part of the latest release but might get featured in the next release of SymPy. You can find it in the current [development version](https://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/plotting.html#plotgrid-class) of SymPy.